# Do I get back the feat slot spent on proficiency if I get it from a class level later?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, character-advancement

If I take Medium Armor Proficiency feat and Martial Weapon Proficiency feat, then later take a level in barbarian, what happens to the feats? Do I "get them back" so I can reuse them? Did I just waste a feat?

This is for a Pathfinder character.

Comment: You can also ask your GM - this is the sort of thing that gets house ruled, which might work in your favour.

Answer (score 16):

Generally speaking, if you receive the same feature twice (whether it's because you invested a Feat and then picked a class granting the same thing, or simply because you have two classes that grant you the same proficiency) it simply means that one of the two copies is wasted.

However, Pathfinder features a set of [Retraining Rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/campaignSystems/retraining.html) that allow you to retrain character choices that you no longer want, which you can use to replace the feat with a different one, but it takes money and time.

Comment: Of course, not all campaigns use Ultimate Campaign material; Check with your GM to see whether this is an option.